# Как перенести параметры из файла в компонент

Tags: c#, winforms

Представим что есть файл.txt в котором есть информация об кнопке, её цвет и т.д,
и как же кнопке узнать что существует такой файл.txt который должен с ней взаимодействовать? Вообще не представляю как это реализовать может кто-нибудь помочь?

Comment: Напишите наверно конечную вашу задачу, для чего это вам? Может вы не в том направление идете и вам стоит например взглянуть на WPF с ее системой стилей?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону сериализации/десериализации данных в экземпляр класса (например CustomButtonStyle).

Comment: Знание о внешних параметрах нужно вписывать в сам код. Самое простое - при загрузке программы проверяем есть ли файл с заданным именем. Если есть - читаем его. если чтение параметров прошло успешно - применяем параметры к кнопке. Если нет - ничего не делаем, кнопка остается такой какая есть.